# React/Redux/Router client-side login credentials - restricted page

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I'm new to React/Redux/Router, and am curious to know if it is possible to do something like this:

```
if (user.loggedIn) {
  // redirect to '/dashboard'
} else {
  // redirect to '/'
}
```

I want to restrict access of `dashboard` to a `current user`.  If I copy `www.mysite.com/dashboard` onto another browser, it would redirect to `www.mysite.com/`.

The `user.loggedIn` state would ideally be determined client-side.

How would this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering `user.loggedIn` is available in client - side, This can be achieved using a simple redirect with Router.

```
<Route exact path="/" render={() => (
  user.loggedIn ? (
    <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>
  ) : (
    <HomePage />
  )
)}/>
```

Please refer to https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Redirect.md

Comment: I'm quite new with `React` so on a site creator like `Create React App` or `Gatsby` where would I put this `Route` file? Thanks!

Comment: You will have a file called Route.js with a render method. You'd ideally want to put this in the `render()` method within that file.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different patterns you could use to achieve this. I would consider something along the lines of the following:

- Connect the component serving your router to your Redux store.
- Map a `prop` named `isLoggedIn` to `state.auth.user != null` or similar in your Redux store.
- Conditionally serve the `/` or `/Dashboard` route based on this prop.
- To initially set the user in your state container, you would need to write an authentication flow as appropriate to your application.